# Have nginx send files as binary downloads

Tags: nginx

I currently have two directories.  `app/static` and `app/static/downloads` what I would like to accomplish is have nginx work normally for all files and folders in static, like it does now.

```
location /static/ {
    alias /home/www/api.to/static/;
    expires 35d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    access_log off;
}
```

But I would like to send all the files in `/static/downloads` subdirectories, such as `static/downloads/blah/blah.pdf` as binary.

Do I need to make a new server block for this? How would I accomplish this?

In other words, I have an app that offers users the file. But since this is a `cdn.app` URL, it opens the files in a new browser tab instead of sending it as a download.

Comment: What do you mean by, “But since this is a cdn.app URL…”

Comment: The files are being called from another site.  Say app.com vs cdn.app.com is where they are stored.

Comment: Then where is this Nginx config going? The `cdn.app.com` config is 100% different from `app.com` if they are different servers. Whatever you need to do, you need to adjust the config for `cdn.app.com`.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I did adjust the cdn.app.com config, and it didn't work with the solution you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force Nginx to download files, do something like this in your config:

```
location /static/downloads {
   add_header Content-disposition "attachment; filename=$1";
   default_type application/octet-stream;
}
```

Restart, Nginx and anything in `/static/downloads` should be downloaded instead of processed as HTML and such.

More details can be [found here](https://fedingo.com/how-to-force-download-file-in-nginx/).

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work.  I think I need to clarify the files are in sub directories in the downloads directory, ie `static/downloads/blah/blah.pdf`